# Deleting an item from a scene

Tags: python, mouseevent, pyqt4, qgraphicsscene

I currently am having an issue with a delete button I created that is linked to a QGraphicsScene class.  The button is created in the Window class not the MyView class.  I am trying to have the user be able to delete marks that were made on a scene but right now it is only deleting the last ellipse item I create and nothing else.  The error that pops up usually says that the other objects you are trying to delete are in a different scene.  Also the location of the circle object that wants to be deleted is important.  So if the user has the cursor over a particular circle that circle item should delete and nothing else.  Here's my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
#this sets the scene for drawing and the microscope image
class MyView(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self,window):
        QtGui.QGraphicsView.__init__(self)
        self.window = window
        self.scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.item = QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem(400, 400, 400, 400)
        self.scene.addItem(self.item)
        self.setScene(self.scene)
    def paintMarkers(self,event):
        ##self.cursor = QtGui.QCursor()
        #self.cursor.setShape(2)
        p = self.mapToScene(event.x(),event.y())
        self.circleItem = QtGui.QGraphicsEllipseItem(p.x(),p.y(),5,5)
        self.scene.addItem(self.circleItem)
        self.circleItem.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.red, 1.5))
        #self.setScene(self.scene)
    def deleteMarkers(self):
        self.scene.removeItem(self.circleItem)
        #print "Hello world"
    #def mousePressEvent(self,QMouseEvent):
        #self.paintMarkers()
    def mousePressEvent(self,event):
        if self.window.btnPaintDot.isChecked():
            self.paintMarkers(event)
        if self.window.btnDeleteMarks.isChecked():
            self.deleteMarkers()
        return QtGui.QGraphicsView.mousePressEvent(self,event)




class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
            #This initializes the main window or form
            super(Window,self).__init__()
            self.setGeometry(50,50,1000,1000)
            self.setWindowTitle("Pre-Alignment system")

            self.view = MyView()
            self.setCentralWidget(self.view)
    #makes deletemarks button checked when pressed
        def paintDeleteMarks(self):
            if self.btnDeleteMarks.isChecked():
                self.btnPaintDot.setChecked(False)
                self.btnPaintPolygon.setChecked(False)
                self.btnPaintPolygon.setChecked(False)
                self.btnDeleteMarks.setChecked(True)
            else:
                self.btnDeleteMarks.setChecked(False)
```

Much thanks please ask questions if my explanation needs more...well explaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you carefully read over your code, you will see that you are deleting the item stored in `self.circleItem`. The item stored in that variable is **always** only the last one created (you overwrite the variable each time you create a new item).

You need to modify your code so that it finds items based on the current x-y coordinate of the mouse event. Use [`QGraphicsScene.itemAt()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html#itemAt-3) to find the item at a particular x-y coordinate (remember to correctly transform the coordinates relative to the scene before looking up the item at that location).

Comment: I would have to use mapToScene() method correct? kind of what you told me with my question a few days ago to get the proper location?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that fixed the issue thanks to three_pineapples!

```
    import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
#this sets the scene for drawing and the microscope image
class MyView(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self,window):
        QtGui.QGraphicsView.__init__(self)
        self.window = window
        self.scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.item = QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem(400, 400, 400, 400)
        self.scene.addItem(self.item)
        self.setScene(self.scene)
    def paintMarkers(self,event):
        ##self.cursor = QtGui.QCursor()
        #self.cursor.setShape(2)
        p = self.mapToScene(event.x(),event.y())
        if (p.x() > 400 and p.x() < 800) and (p.y() > 400 and p.y() < 800):
            self.circleItem = QtGui.QGraphicsEllipseItem(p.x(),p.y(),5,5)
        self.scene.addItem(self.circleItem)
        self.circleItem.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.red, 1.5))
        #self.setScene(self.scene)
    def deleteMarkers(self,event):
        p = self.mapToScene(event.x(),event.y())
        if self.scene.itemAt(p.x(),p.y()) != self.item:
            self.scene.removeItem(self.scene.itemAt(p.x(),p.y()))
        #print "Hello world"
    #def mousePressEvent(self,QMouseEvent):
        #self.paintMarkers()
    def mousePressEvent(self,event):
        if self.window.btnPaintDot.isChecked():
            self.paintMarkers(event)
        if self.window.btnDeleteMarks.isChecked():
            self.deleteMarkers(event)
        return QtGui.QGraphicsView.mousePressEvent(self,event)
```